# Reference Parent Array Key In Recursive Function

Tags: php

I'm struggling to understand why this doesnt work. I mean, am I getting references wrong? Is the some other mistake I dont see?

What I want to do is set the parent element to active if the child element is active. In order to do this I pass a reference to the parent element to the recursive function call.

But somehow it doesnt get updated in the actual menu tree. Only in the local variable.

I'm open to other solutions but also really wanna know whats going wrong here.

```
private static function buildMenuTree($menus, &$parentTreeItem) {
    $tree = array();

    // loop through every menu item
    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        // check if a parent menu exists, if not $parentId will bet set to 0
        $parentId = !array_key_exists('menu', $parentTreeItem) ? null : $parentTreeItem['menu']->id;

        // initialize new menu entry
        $currentTreeItem = [];

        // check current menu entry belongs to what was provided to us
        if($menu->parent == $parentId) {

            //set menu
            $currentTreeItem['menu'] = $menu;

            // check if route matches, then set the isActive flag
            if(Request::is($menu->route)) {
                $currentTreeItem['isActive'] = true;

                //if there is a valid parent, also set the isActiveFlag on the parent
                // TODO: this is changed on the local vaiable but not in the menu tree
                if($parentId != null) {
                    $parentTreeItem['isActive'] = true;
                }
            } else {
                $currentTreeItem['isActive'] = false;
            }


            // build menu tree for current item
            $currentTreeItem['menus'] = self::buildMenuTree($menus, $currentTreeItem);
            // add current item to menu tree
            $tree[] = $currentTreeItem;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: By "doesn't work", can you explain what you expect and what actually happens? Until then some general advice, step through it one line at a time and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, yeah i should have stated it in the question, not in the code. TODO: this is changed on the local vaiable but not in the menu tree